# Why I can catch the java.lang.SecurityException with root in android launcher app

Tags: android, permissions, widget, root, securityexception

I build a launcher app , my phone had already be `rooted`,and my app had already got the `root permission`,but the `log` showed me these

```
" java.lang.SecurityException: bindGagetId appWidgetId=322 provider=ComponentInfo{com.moji.mjweather/com.moji.mjweather.CMojiWidget4x1}: User 10018 does not have android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET.  "
```

when I add a widget......Why?I  can't understand!!!

Comment: Could you add the full logcat? Also did you add this permission `android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET` ?

Comment: another logs is not useful,I had already add that permission,and my app had got the root permission.